# Is it possible in GKE to assign a specific outbound IP Address to a Pod when using Cloud NAT with multiple static IP adresses?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, gke-networking

I'm running a private GKE cluster with Cloud NAT. Cloud NAT has multiple static ip addresses assigned. Is it possible for me to tell a pod to always use one of those ip addresses as source ip?

Comment: Hello, have you seen following documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#NATwithGKE), [2](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) by any chance? I'd reckon what you are trying to do is not possible. Could you please tell more about what exactly are you trying to achieve or the use case of it? Maybe there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question:

> Is it possible in GKE to assign a specific outbound IP Address to a Pod when using Cloud NAT with multiple static IP addresses?

**In short, no.** There is no option to modify the `Cloud NAT` (and `Cloud Router`) in a way that would make specific `Pods` to have a specific IP address when connecting to the external sources.

You could also consider creating a Feature Request for it at:

- *[Issuetracker.google.com: Issues: GKE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=1162696)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: Overview: NAT with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#NATwithGKE)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: GKE example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)*